# How to send the ranges selected automatically through vba

Tags: vba

I'm using the code below to select ranges from two different worksheets and sending through email. It all works well however when I run the code the selected ranges are dropped into a new email window but does not send automatically. I try to add ".send" after ".HTMLBody" but does not seem to work. Any help would be appreciated.

Sub due()

```
Dim ol As Object 'Outlook.Application
Dim olEmail As Object 'Outlook.MailItem
Dim olInsp As Object 'Outlook.Inspector
Dim wd As Object 'Word.Document
Dim rCol As Collection, r As Range, i As Integer

 '/* if outlook is running use GO, create otherwise */
Set ol = GetObject(Class:="Outlook.Application")
Set olEmail = ol.CreateItem(0) 'olMailItem

Set rCol = New Collection
With rCol
    .Add Sheet1.Range("A1:p52") '/* add your ranges the same sequence */
    .Add Sheet2.Range("A1:p17") '/* as you want them added in the body */
End With

With olEmail
    .To = ""
    '/* bonus basic html */
    .HTMLBody = "<html><body style=""font-family:calibri"">" & _
                "<p><b>Dear Deer,</b><br><br> She see seas." & _
                "</p></body></html>"


    Set olInsp = .GetInspector
    If olInsp.EditorType = 4 Then 'olEditorWord
        Set wd = olInsp.WordEditor
        For i = 1 To rCol.Count '/* iterate all ranges */
            Set r = rCol.Item(i): r.Copy
            wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
            wd.Paragraphs(wd.Paragraphs.Count).Range.PasteAndFormat 16
            '16 - wdFormatOriginalFormatting
        Next
    End If
    wd.Range.InsertParagraphAfter
    wd.Paragraphs(wd.Paragraphs.Count).Range.Text = "Regards, Patricia"
    wd.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Sentences.Last.Font.Bold = True
    .Display
End With
```

End Sub

Comment: diti6 wrote ***but does not seem to work***. That is not helpful. Please elaborate on what is not working, error codes etc.

Comment: Ideally I am trying to get to a point where I can create a button on my excel sheet which I can click and it will automatically send out an email which includes the tables in the ranges specified. Currently when I click the button the code brings up a new Outlook page where it includes all the data in the specified ranges, email addresses, subject line ..all I need to do is click send. My goal is to avoid the step where I have to click send and instead have the email be sent from the very first click of the vba button.

Answer (score 0):

Change this:

```
wd.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Sentences.Last.Font.Bold = True
.Display
End With
```

to

```
wd.Paragraphs.Last.Range.Sentences.Last.Font.Bold = True
.Send
End With
```